# UIScrollView didn't scroll

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview

I've some problem with ScrollView.
I'm trying to create a scrollview and add to it dynamically some buttons.

So i create a scrollView in my main storyboard with some constraints. (0 to left, 0 to right, 0 to botton and 1/10 height).
[image: MainStoryBoard]

Now, i want to add some button.

```
@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for index in 0..<12 {
        let frame1 = CGRect(x: 0 + (index * 60), y: 0, width: 45, height: 45 )
        let button = UIButton(frame: frame1)
        button.setTitle("toto", forState: .Normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.green()
        scrollView.addSubview(button)
    }   
}
```

So now the problem is : my buttons are present **but i can't scroll**. The scroll is enabled in the storyBoard. I tried to enabled it in the code but nothing changed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the `contentSize` of your `scrollView`

```
self. scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(required_width, required_height)
```

for example

```
self. scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(500, 74) // custtomize ur self
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the **contentSize** of the scrollView

The height to set is probably the `origin.y` + the `size.height` of the last button.

Answer (score 1):

use this code to set scrollview height

```
scrollview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 50, 0)
//50 is the height of scroll view you can change it to the height you want
scrollview.bounces = false
```

or you can also change content inset from here
by changing the values of content inset (height or width)

[image]